Не получается получить названия файлов в директории MAUI C#
Нужно получить названия файлов в папке, на android ничего не происходит, при этом никакой ошибки нет
<ContentPage>
    <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="verticalStackLayout">
        <Button x:Name="btn" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Open Folder" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

var result = await FolderPicker.PickAsync(default);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(result.Folder.Path);

ListView listView = new ListView() { ItemsSource = files };
verticalStackLayout.Add(listView);

На windows все работает нормально, уже не знаю, что делать


Верное-ли значение в result.Folder.Path? 2. Приложение имеет соответствующие права? 3. Очень сильно советую научиться писать код правильно, ибо new ListView() - это уровень 90-х годов. В современных проектах, особенно в MAUI, есть XAML, где вы и должны писать весь UI, в C# коде должна быть только работа с данными, ни каких verticalStackLayout.Add, и тем более, никаких  new ListView(), это плохо, это ужасно, учитывайте это!



Да верно
Все права указал
Буду учиться

